# Wordpress how to change the way that register_nav_menus outputs menu items

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, menuitem, custom-wordpress-pages, wp-nav-menu-item

I was hoping someone could help me .... I want to change the way that wordpress nav_menus outputs the menu listing.

Currently it outputs the following for example:

```html
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-48"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I would like it to output as follows:

```html
    <ul class="cssMenu">
        <li class="lvl01"><a href="/" class="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="lvl01"><a href="/about/" class="">About</a></li>
        <li class="lvl01"><a href="#" class=""><span>Case Studies</span></a>
            <ul class="">
                <li class="lvl02"><a href="#" class="">Page Title One</a></li>
                <li class="lvl02"><a href="#" class="">Page Title Two</a></li>
                <li class="lvl02"><a href="#" class="">Page Title Three</a></li>
                <li class="lvl02"><a href="#" class="">Page Title Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="lvl01"><a href="/category/news/" class="">News</a></li>
    </ul>
```

If anyone has any clue on how to go about this, i would greatly appreciate some help

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom menu walker. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu and [T5_Nav_Menu_Walker_Simple — Gist](https://gist.github.com/1053467) and http://www.mattvarone.com/wordpress/cleaner-output-for-wp_nav_menu/ and other Google results for "wordpress menu walker."

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on this a little ago.. maybe you'll find it helpful:

[www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/wordpress-wp-nav-menu-tutorial/](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/wordpress-wp-nav-menu-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this Wordpress filter...

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class